# set image all four side in relativelayout in android

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:text="Registraion"
        android:textColor="#0066FF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/white_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/gray_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/gray_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/gray_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/white_round" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my Xml file for layout.
I am unable to set the Image whole Screen its missing some distance from all side here is my image http://snag.gy/aZ54f.jpg  please help me where am doing mistake image should set image from all four side http://snag.gy/AgX8A.jpg like this please help .

Comment: change wrap_content to match_content in imageview for both width and height.

Comment: If i'm not mistaking, you showed use the wrong xml. You should show use the xml file which is added to the viewpager.

Comment: yes i have added view pager so how i will fix it ...whole screen http://snag.gy/AgX8A.jpg like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this, remove padding this way - `android:padding="5dp"` from `LinearLayout`

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Also change `ImageView` to

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/white_round" />
```

**EDIT:**

Based on looking at entire code, the problem was with your fragment layout, here remove the padding from it, see code below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Final view is

[image]

Comment: i see 4 `ImageView` which one are you using for background image?? try to set to that

Comment: yes that is displaying under view pager problematically but i am unable make it full screen http://snag.gy/AgX8A.jpg like this

Comment: how does final screen look after making above changes??

Comment: try `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to LinearLayout

Comment: i changed but its not coming, change the 
`imageview.setFitToScreen(true);
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);` in dummy fragment code, did it helped??

Comment: that takes care of aspect ratio too for image

Comment: imageview.setFitToScreen(true);  this is not workingg

Comment: `imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`, this ??

Comment: can you send the code to me, to actually take a look at it??

Comment: yes i can http://paste.ofcode.org/gVVtmUfbxKwZKHERB5X3n4  this class name ok  this is XMl FIle   bg1,bg2,bg3...bg5 are 5 image u use any image if u have skype id then i can send u direclty code coz here gmail is not activated

Comment: plz add me on Skype i sent request

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem in your xml instead it is the image which is being rendered is not big enough to display the whole screen.

Instead programmatically add some layoutParams to the viewPager to scale the image to required type.

In your code add layoutParams in,

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);
                    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            layout.addView(imageView, lp);

            imageview.setImageResource(images[getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)]);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, You can change to whichever alignment you want. In my case I used CENTER_IN_PARENT. Hope it works for you.

Comment: mContext  will getApplicationContext or what

Comment: Ya it is same as your getApplicationContext